# How to increase the amount of previous command text bash will scroll to?

Tags: bash

I am try to debug an nginx configuration file with

```
tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

with error logging level set to debug (very verbose).
the amount text the passed into `error.log` is maybe 5-10 screens worth.
When I scroll up to view the entire debug entry, bash doesn't allow scrolling up that far, so I only have some of the debug entry viewable.

Is it possible to get bash to allow viewing/scrolling to more than just a few screens worth of previous history?

Comment: You could run the command in `tmux` and set a high `history-limit`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I understood your question but...
If you have a gnome terminal or similar, you can try to:

in your terminal:

```
(right button 
  select profile
    profile preferences 
      scrolling
```

and change the number of lines for scrolling

Comment: This assumes that the OP has a teminal that works like this (many don't)...

Comment: @jasonwryan you are right of course...

Comment: Im on ubuntu with unity desktop and it worked perfectly, @jasonwryan 's `tmux` suggesting is interesting but currently dont have time to research it, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

This is a terminal or terminal emulator specific setting and doesn't have anything to do with bash.  If you are using a terminal that doesn't support much scroll back or a pty, I would recommend using tmux with a high history limit.

If you are logged into a PTY, you should also be able to pipe 'tail -f'  into less.

EDIT: Tail -f /var/log/xxxx | less will work even if you are using a terminal emulator and not a PTY.

Answer (score 1):

use `less`. or use `tail -n X` where `X` is the number of lines which should be displayed.

Comment: thanks, that involves re-running the command every time a webpage is viewed (and log file is updated). I'm hoping to tail the file as it gets updated

Comment: `less` also has a "follow"-mode: Shift-F

Comment: because `less -F` is paging , it actually only shows 1 screen and nothing else, so no scrolling at all

Comment: The point is that with `less` in follow mode, if you want to scroll back, you can simply hit ctrl-C and then page back (or use search, etc.); resume follow follow mode witha simple shift-F.

Answer (score 1):

If you use PuTTY you can set the value in the configuration category Window / Lines of scrollback